# Plotting a list vs a list of arrays with matplotlib

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy, matplotlib

Let's say I have two lists `a` and `b`, whereas one is a list of arrays

```
a = [1200, 1400, 1600, 1800]

b = [array([ 1.84714754,  4.94204658, 11.61580355, ..., 17.09772144,
       17.09537562, 17.09499705]), array([ 3.08541849,  5.11338795, 10.26957508, ..., 16.90633304,
       16.90417909, 16.90458781]), array([ 4.61916789,  4.58351918,  4.37590053, ..., -2.76705271,
       -2.46715664, -1.94577492]), array([7.11040853, 7.79529924, 8.48873734, ..., 7.78736448, 8.47749987,
       9.36040364])]
```

The shape of both is said to be `(4,)`

If I now try to plot these via `plt.scatter(a, b)`

I get an error I can't relate to: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

At the end I want a plot where per n-th value in `a` a set of values stored as n-th array in `b` shall be plotted.

I'm pretty sure I've done this before, but I can't get this working.
Any ideas? ty

Comment: What does `np.array(b)` or `np.stack(b)` do?

Comment: `np.array(b)` returns the same error and `np.stack(b)` returns `ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape`

Comment: That tells you what's wrong!

Comment: Well, but I don't see a smart solution. Also it's a bit contradicting if I'm asking for the shape and it is for both `(4,)`. What's the best way from here? Filling `a` with redundant entries to have the same shape as b? Seems weird to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust the elements in a to match the elements in b

```py
len_b = [len(sub_array) for sub_array in b]
a = [repeat_a for i,repeat_a in enumerate(a) for _ in range(len_b[i])]

# convert list of array to just list of values
b = np.ravel(b).tolist()

# check if lengths are same
assert len(a) == len(b)
# if yes, now this should work
plt.scatter(a,b)
```

Comment: Thanks. I get what you suggest. I guess it could work. However `b = np.ravel(b).tolist()` doesn't collapse the arrays to a single list as I thought it should do. I'll add an answer below for clarification.

Comment: If `np.shape(b)` is (4,) `np.ravel` won't change that.  `np.hstack(b)` should join the arrays into one, regardless of their individual lengths.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid repetition it is. If all lists in `b` have the same length, you can use [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#fake data
np.random.seed(123)
a = [1200, 1400, 1600, 1800]
b = np.random.randint(1, 100, (4, 11)).tolist()

plt.scatter(np.repeat(a, len(b[0])), b)

plt.show()
```

If you are not sure and want to be on the safe side, list comprehension it is.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#fake data
np.random.seed(123)
a = [1200, 1400, 1600, 1800]
b = np.random.randint(1, 100, (4, 11)).tolist()

plt.scatter([[x]*len(b[i]) for i, x in enumerate(a)], b)

plt.show()
```

The output is the same:
[image: ![![enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the suggestion of @sai I tried

```
import numpy as np

arr0 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
arr1 = np.array([6, 7, 8, 9])
arr2 = np.array([10, 11])

old_b = [arr0, arr1, arr2]
b = np.ravel(old_b).tolist()

print(len(b))
```

Which will give me length 3 instead of the length 11 I expected. How can I collapse a list of arrays to a single list?

edit:

```
b = np.concatenate(old_b).ravel().tolist()
```

will lead to the desired result. Thanks all.